# ImportError: cannot import name 'CapturedException' from 'pyspark.sql.utils'

Tags: pyspark, delta-lake

dependencies:

```
pyspark==3.4.0
delta-spark==2.0.0
python==3.11.4
```

Code snippet to reproduce:

```
from delta import configure_spark_with_delta_pip
```

Error Log:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 6
      3 from enum import Enum
      4 from datetime import datetime
----> 6 from delta import configure_spark_with_delta_pip
      7 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
      8 from pyspark.sql.types import (ArrayType, BinaryType, BooleanType, ByteType,
      9                                FloatType, IntegerType, ShortType, StringType,
     10                                StructField, StructType, TimestampType)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/delta/__init__.py:17
      1 #
      2 # Copyright (2021) The Delta Lake Project Authors.
      3 #
   (...)
     14 # limitations under the License.
     15 #
---> 17 from delta.tables import DeltaTable
     18 from delta.pip_utils import configure_spark_with_delta_pip
     20 __all__ = ['DeltaTable', 'configure_spark_with_delta_pip']

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/delta/tables.py:21
      1 #
      2 # Copyright (2021) The Delta Lake Project Authors.
      3 #
   (...)
     14 # limitations under the License.
     15 #
     17 from typing import (
     18     TYPE_CHECKING, cast, overload, Any, Iterable, Optional, Union, NoReturn, List, Tuple
     19 )
---> 21 import delta.exceptions  # noqa: F401; pylint: disable=unused-variable
     22 from delta._typing import (
     23     ColumnMapping, OptionalColumnMapping, ExpressionOrColumn, OptionalExpressionOrColumn
     24 )
     26 from pyspark import since

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/delta/exceptions.py:21
     19 from pyspark import SparkContext
     20 from pyspark.sql import utils
---> 21 from pyspark.sql.utils import (
     22     AnalysisException,
     23     CapturedException,
     24     IllegalArgumentException,
     25     ParseException
     26 )
     27 from py4j.java_gateway import is_instance_of  # type: ignore[import]
     29 if TYPE_CHECKING:

ImportError: cannot import name 'CapturedException' from 'pyspark.sql.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py)
```

More info:

```
pyspark==3.2.2
delta-spark==2.0.0
python==3.10
```

will works well in this case.

Comment: Try upgrading to delta-spark 2.4.0

Comment: Hi @ewokx Thanks you for your solution
This method works, FYI

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adopting @ewokx's sulution 'upgrade delta-spark to 2.4.0'

Thanks to @ewokx